# Moving an mp3 file to podcasts without PC

Tags: 8.0, podcast

minor problem here.
I have an mp3 file that I downloaded through OneDrive. It should be added to podcasts, yet it just sits there. It can be opened and listened to, but I cannot add it to any playlist, nor to the podcasts app. Is there any way to do it WITHOUT using any PC?
Using WP8, by the way.

Comment: The podcast app seems to be fetching information from the cloud as opposed to locally and seems to be built to work that way. How about using the `Files` app to move the file to the music folder and then add it to a playlist?